# Required Throwable found SlickException when initializing states

Tags: java

When I write this statment 
 throws a SlickException. I got an error 
and this is the message: `required Throwable found SlickException`.
This my code :

```
public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException{
    this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
     this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
     this.enterState(menu);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The initStateList method is there for you to add states, not initialize them. Slick will initialize them for you and enter the first state you added automatically.

It should look like this:

```
public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    addState(new YourFirstState();
    addState(new YourSecondState();
    ...
    }
```

Then slick will automatically initialize them and enter "YourFirstState"